# Combining different data of two lists into one

Tags: c#

So if i got 3 classes: one holds data of the Driver(his name, license plate),second which holds the cars data(trademark,license plate,year it was made,mileage),third should hold(Taksi) the data like drivers name,registration plate,year the car was made.

```
public class Car : Taksi
{
    public string Trademark { get; set; }
    public new int RegPlate { get; set; }
    public int YearMade { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public Car (string Trademark, int RegPlate, int YearMade, int Mileage)
    {
        this.Trademark = Trademark;
        this.RegPlate = RegPlate;
        this.YearMade = YearMade;
        this.Mileage = Mileage;
    }
}

public class Driver : Taksi
{
    public new string Name { get; set; }
    public new int RegPlate { get; set; }
    public Driver(string Name , int RegPlate )
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.RegPlate = RegPlate ;
    }
}

public class Taksi
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RegPlate { get; set; }
    public string Trademark { get; set; }
    public int YearMade { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public Taksi()
    {
    }
    public Taksi(string Name,string Trademark,int YearMade)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Trademark = Trademark;
        this.YearMade = YearMade;
    }
}
```

Problem is that i have two lists. First list holds data of driver and the second holds data of the car. Now i dont know what is the best way to to take parts of data(Name,regplate,yearmade) of the "Car" and "Driver"classes then have them combined and added to

```
List<Taksi> Taks = new List<Taksi>();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible

Comment: Using LINQ Join may be what you are looking for : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Merge objects? If so, on what property?

Comment: I believe you've already solved the problem. What you're trying to do should be possible.

Comment: Is there a reason why in your derived class you create new properties for Name & RegPlate rather than using the fields in the base class?

Comment: In your current data structure, the `Driver` class has a `YearMade` property. This is clearly wrong. What I would suggest is to remove the inheritance from `Taksi`, and instead an instance of `Taksi` should have  `Driver` and `Car` properties.

Comment: Adriani6 answering to your question, i have two .txt files, one holds drivers data and other one holds car data.I need to make a list where if the drivers regplate equals "Car" regplate then i need to add it to a new list and data that has been added has to contain only name of the driver, regplate, trademark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you reconsider your class structure - a Driver is not a type of Taksi so should not be derived from that class. A Taksi could be consider a combination of a Driver & a Car, so rather than derive a Car from a Taksi, a Taksi should be derived from a Car (basically you view a Taksi as a type of Car - rather than a Car as a type of Taksi).

```
public class Car
{
    public string Trademark { get; set; }
    public int YearMade { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public int RegPlate { get; set; }
    public Car (string Trademark, int RegPlate, int YearMade, int Mileage)
    {
        this.Trademark = Trademark;
        this.RegPlate = RegPlate;
        this.YearMade = YearMade;
        this.Mileage = Mileage;
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RegPlate { get; set; }
    public Driver(string Name , int RegPlate )
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.RegPlate = RegPlate ;
    }
}

public class Taksi : Car
{
    public Driver TaksiDriver { get; set; }
    public Taksi(Driver TaksiDriver, Car TaksiCar)
      : base(TaksiCar.Trademark, TaksiCar.RegPlate, TaksiCar.YearMade, TaksiCar.Mileage)
    {
        this.TaksiDriver = TaksiDriver;
    }
}
```

You could then combine your list of Cars & Drivers like this :

```
  List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(); 
  List<Driver> drivers = new List<Driver>();
  .....
  .....

  List<Taksi> taksis = (from car in cars
    join driver in drivers on car.RegPlate equals driver.RegPlate
    select new Taksi( driver, car )).ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, BTW, Car class no need so many property.

```
var cars = new List<Car>();
var drivers = new List<Driver>();

var taksi = from c in cars
            from d in drivers
            where c.RegPlate == d.RegPlate
            select new Taksi()
            {
                 Name = d.Name,
                 RegPlate = d.RegPlate,
                 Trademark = c.Trademark,
                 YearMade = c.YearMade,
                 Mileage = c.Mileage
            };
```